# Aws looks for credentials even if I hardcode them

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The PHP SDK of AWS looks for credentials in a directory even if I hardcode them.

Please note that this is a known issue if 'profile' is defined. However, this even happens if 'profile' is not defined.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Translate\TranslateClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

// Hard-coded credentials
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-west-2',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $key,
        'secret' => $secret,
    ],
]);
```

]);

...gives:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials in C:\xampp\htdocs\ModernMT\frontend\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Credentials\CredentialProvider.php:874
```

Why?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `$key` and `$secret` are not null or empty?

Comment: Absolutely sure! I even echo'd their output. Meanwhile I found another solution using https://github.com/ttsuruoka/php-simple-amazon-dynamodb , but the above indeed isn't working, despite what their documentation says.